# Autologin users from their e-mail messages (via hyperlink)

Tags: hash, authentication

I'm working on a system that sends out e-mail notifications when users comment to other users' threads. Think of it as a forum or blog. Now when a user receives a comment, he also receives an e-mail notification saying "hey, there's a comment for you here" together with a link to the comment.

What I'd like to do is make that link special, clicking on which the user can by-pass the login process and receive the session cookies automatically. We can trust this since he's got access to the e-mail account. There are some social networks that implement this, and I want to know what the best practices are.

Obviously I have to tag links with a special hash and check the hash somewhere in my middleware to set the cookies accordingly. The hash may contain the user's e-mail address, password, salt (obviously) and something else. I'd like to figure out what that "something else is" and I'd like such links to get expired after 14 days.

Should I generate 14 hashes in my middleware (one for each day starting today and ending 14 days before) and compare them to the one received? Is that a good idea?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a database table where you store a hash, when it was generated, and the infos you mentionated: loginID, questionID, commentID, or any ID you find relevant.

When the user clicks in the link, you'll search your DB, verify if it is inside the valid period, automatically login the user (sending him cookies or something else), them delete the hash from your table (since it has been used).